# Android Parcelable Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I am crafting a non profit charity app. Despite I have checked many questions in stack and google, i could not solve the problem.
I have 3 classes:
 - BaseCell implements Parcelable (Base class)
 - Needy extends BaseCell
 - UserBasket class which hold the list of all classes extend BaseCell

#### Problem

I am holding Needy classes with Arraylist in UserBasket class. When i send it to another activity, if i add 1 item to the UserBasket i am getting ridiculous result(Missing or wrong characters) and if i add more than 1 item then i am getting exception.

I need to deliver UserBasket class(list of needy items) to the payment activity so i can calculate the total price for charity and perform necessary actions.

```
public abstract class BaseCell implements Parcelable {


String imageUrl;
int percentageOfCollectedDonation;
String needyTitle;
String needyDescription;

protected String category;
protected int amountOfCollectedDonation=0;
protected int amountOfTargetDonation=0;
protected int amountOfDonater=0;
protected int drawableID;
protected String campaignCode;

protected int maxInstallmentNumber;

int price;

public String getCellType() {
    return cellType;
}

protected String cellType ;

/**
 * How many of this campaign purchased by user
 * */
protected int userPurchaseAmount = 1;

protected BaseCell(String cellType)
{
    this.cellType = cellType;
}
protected BaseCell(Parcel in)
{

    drawableID = in.readInt();
    price = in.readInt();
    imageUrl = in.readString();
    needyTitle = in.readString();
    needyDescription = in.readString();
    category = in.readString();
    campaignCode = in.readString();
    maxInstallmentNumber = in.readInt();
    userPurchaseAmount = in.readInt();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<BaseCell> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<BaseCell>() {
    @Override
    public BaseCell createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        String cellType = in.readString();
        BaseCell baseCell = null;

        if (cellType.equals("Needy"))
        {
            baseCell = (Needy)new Needy(in);
        }else
        if (cellType.equals("Qurban"))
        {
            baseCell = (Qurban)new Qurban(in);
        }

        return baseCell;
    }

    @Override
    public BaseCell[] newArray(int size) {
        return new BaseCell[size];
    }
};
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(getCellType());
}


public BaseCell(String imageUrl, int drawableID, String needyTitle, String needyDescription, int amountOfCollectedDonation, int amountOfTargetDonation, int amountOfDonater, String category,String campaignCode, int maxInstallmentNumber, int price)
{
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.drawableID = drawableID;
    this.needyTitle = needyTitle;
    this.needyDescription = needyDescription;
    this.amountOfCollectedDonation = amountOfCollectedDonation;
    this.amountOfTargetDonation = amountOfTargetDonation;
    this.amountOfDonater = amountOfDonater;
    this.category = category;
    this.campaignCode = campaignCode;
    this.maxInstallmentNumber = maxInstallmentNumber;
    this.price= price;
}


}
```

#### Needy

```
    public class Needy extends BaseCell {

    protected Needy(Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    cellType ="Needy";
    }



public static final Parcelable.Creator<Needy> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Needy>() {
    @Override
    public Needy createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Needy(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Needy[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Needy[size];
    }
};


public Needy(String imageUrl, int drawableID, String needyTitle, String needyDescription, int amountOfCollectedDonation, int amountOfTargetDonation, int amountOfDonater, String category, String campaignCode, int maxInstallmentNumber, int price) {

    super(imageUrl, drawableID, needyTitle, needyDescription, amountOfCollectedDonation, amountOfTargetDonation, amountOfDonater, category, campaignCode, maxInstallmentNumber,price);
    cellType = "Needy";
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(getCellType());
    super.writeToParcel(dest,flags);
    dest.writeInt(drawableID);
    dest.writeInt(price);
    dest.writeString(imageUrl);
    dest.writeString(needyTitle);
    dest.writeString(needyDescription);
    dest.writeString(category);
    dest.writeString(campaignCode);
    dest.writeInt(maxInstallmentNumber);
    dest.writeInt(userPurchaseAmount);
}

@Override
public void setUserPurchaseAmount(int userPurchaseAmount) {
    super.setUserPurchaseAmount(userPurchaseAmount);
 }
}
```

#### UserBasket

```
    public class UserBasket implements Parcelable{


List<BaseCell> userBasket;

/**
 * holds all items to be purchased
 * */
public UserBasket(List<BaseCell> userBasket) {
    this.userBasket = userBasket;
}

public UserBasket() {
    userBasket = new ArrayList<>();
}


protected UserBasket(Parcel in) {
    super();
    setUserBasket(new ArrayList<BaseCell>());
    userBasket = in.createTypedArrayList(BaseCell.CREATOR);
    //in.readTypedList(userBasket,BaseCell.CREATOR);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<UserBasket> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<UserBasket>() {
    @Override
    public UserBasket createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new UserBasket(in);
    }

    @Override
    public UserBasket[] newArray(int size) {
        return new UserBasket[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeTypedList(userBasket);
}



public List<BaseCell> getUserBasket() {
    return userBasket;
}

public void setUserBasket(List<BaseCell> userBasket) {
    this.userBasket = userBasket;
}

/**
 * Add to the basket list
 * */
public void add(Needy donation) {
    if (donation != null)
        userBasket.add(donation);
}

/**
 * Remove from basket list
 * */
public void remove(int position)
{
    if (userBasket.size()>0)
        userBasket.remove(position);
}

}
```

sending userBasket arrayList with items from MainActivity
        Navigate.navigateToPaymentPayuStart
        (MainActivity.this,userBasket,"basket"); 
        // userBasket arrayList with "basket" key
        Receiving UserBasket in paymentPayu activity
        UserBasket userBasket = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("basket");
How am i going to get UserBasket properly in paymentPayuActivity.
I appreciate for the help
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem like you are handling the `Parcelable` implementation wrong. e.i. you are reading some of the variables from the `Parcel` twice, which isn't allowed. So to improve this, we'll try to make your code a bit simpler. As `Needy` doesn't actually have any variables, it seems better to let `BaseCell` handle all of the parcelable implementation, i've tried to create a mock for you, so depending on the rest of your code it might need a bit of tweaking.

First i've removed all of the `Parcelable` implementation in `Needy` and is just pointing it's `CREATOR` to `BaseCell`.

```
public class Needy extends BaseCell {

    protected Needy(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        cellType ="Needy";
    }

    // Since Needy doesn't actually store any variables, we don't need a Creator for it.
    // Just point it to BaseCell.CREATOR and let it handle it
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<BaseCell> CREATOR = BaseCell.CREATOR;

    public Needy(String imageUrl, int drawableID, String needyTitle, String needyDescription, int amountOfCollectedDonation, int amountOfTargetDonation, int amountOfDonater, String category, String campaignCode, int maxInstallmentNumber, int price) {
        super(imageUrl, drawableID, needyTitle, needyDescription, amountOfCollectedDonation, amountOfTargetDonation, amountOfDonater, category, campaignCode, maxInstallmentNumber,price);
        cellType = "Needy";
    }

}
```

And then we'll let `BaseCell` handle all of the `Parcelable` implementation, like so:

```
public abstract class BaseCell implements Parcelable {

    /**
     * ALL OF YOUR VARIABLES, GETTERS, SETTERS AND CONSTRUCTORS GOES HERE
     */

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<BaseCell> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<BaseCell>() {
        @Override
        public BaseCell createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            String cellType = in.readString();
            if (cellType.equals("Needy")) {
                return (Needy)new Needy(in);
            } else if (cellType.equals("Qurban")) {
                return (Qurban)new Qurban(in);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public BaseCell[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BaseCell[size];
        }
    };

    protected BaseCell(Parcel in) {
        drawableID = in.readInt();
        price = in.readInt();
        imageUrl = in.readString();
        needyTitle = in.readString();
        needyDescription = in.readString();
        category = in.readString();
        campaignCode = in.readString();
        maxInstallmentNumber = in.readInt();
        userPurchaseAmount = in.readInt();
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        // cellType written first, and read by Creator
        out.writeString(cellType);
        // the rest is read by the BaseCell constructor
        out.writeInt(drawableID);
        out.writeInt(price);
        out.writeString(imageUrl);
        out.writeString(needyTitle);
        out.writeString(needyDescription);
        out.writeString(category);
        out.writeString(campaignCode);
        out.writeInt(maxInstallmentNumber);
        out.writeInt(userPurchaseAmount);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know what your `Qurban` class looks like, so i cannot guarentee that the code above will work 100%.

Comment: Thank you, i will try more with BaseCell.

Comment: Qurban is just another class that extends from Basecell but , i did not add any Qurban class into userBasket.

Comment: No problem. By the way if you are using Android Studio, there is a plugin callled 'Android Parcelable code generator' generates the boilerplate code for you. It's a very handy tool. You can find it in 'preferences -> plugins' and then just search for it :-)

Comment: If i have an extra arrayList in Qurban class, have can i write that arraylist to Parcel, couse when i need to write it again in Qurban class i m getting error, like you said before second time writing to parcel is not allowed, so is there a way to implement arraylist that belongs to only Qurban class, need to deliver all properties in BaseClass + arraylist in Qurban class.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, plugin is really nice, and i solved the question that i asked in the previous comment. Looks like my brain.dll gave me an error cause of focusing too much  :)